# Handling redirects with Codeigniter and jQuery mobile?

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, jquery-mobile, tankauth

I'm building a mobile web app with jQuery mobile and Codeigniter & TankAuth. When a user logs in or out, they are redirected from the TankAuth login/logout controller to a page of my choice. The problem is that while the ajax navigation loads the page in question, the URL to the TankAuth controller stays the same.

There is quite a lot of code involved, so I will describe it the best I can:

Consider the variable `$this->session->flashdata('prev_page')` is `page1`.

The TankAuth login controller is called first time via `auth/login`, loads login form view.

The form is submitted to the same controller which then processes it and redirects to necessary page:

```
if ($this->tank_auth->login(
    $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
    $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
    $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
    $data['login_by_username'],
    $data['login_by_email'])) {// success
     redirect($this->session->flashdata('prev_page'));
   }
```

jQuery mobile loads `page1` via AJAX but the URL remains as `auth/login`.
How do I fix this? Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `data-url="true"` to the the form in opening `<form>` tag in question, everything worked fine from there.

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding about your problem is correct, you are using ajax for authenticating mobile users and normal redirect method for big screen users.

If that's the situation, then this will do the magic:

```
if ($this->tank_auth->login(
    $this->form_validation->set_value('login'),
    $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
    $this->form_validation->set_value('remember'),
    $data['login_by_username'],
    $data['login_by_email']))
 {// success
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    if($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('prev_page');
        //Now this value 'll reach ajax when authentication is success.
        //Inside Ajax:
        //success: function(data) {
        //    validate data for checking if user is logged in or not.
        //   if(login_is_success)
        //      window.location.href = data;
        //}
    }
    else
        redirect($this->session->flashdata('prev_page'));
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. I'm sorry I couldn't be more clear.  I solved the problem by adding a data-ajax="false" to the form - it now redirects with the correct url.